# Why is $X=A^{-1}+I^{-1 }$ not equal to $X=(A+I)^{-1}$? Matrices

Tags: matrices

If i simplify  $X=(A+I)^{-1}$ won't i get $X=A^{-1}+I^{-1 }$? Im getting  different solutions when using an online calculator...

Comment: For the exact same reason that $1 / (2 + 3) \ne 1 / 2 + 1/3$.

Comment: Is $(10+1)^{-1}=10^{-1}+1^{-1}$?

Comment: Or does $ 1/2 = (1 + 1)^{-1}= 1^{-1} + 1^{-1} = 1 + 1 = 2$ look right?

Comment: Ok, then its not possible to simplify the $X=(A+I)^{-1}$ like it is if it was a multiplication?

Comment: If x was that number then what happens if you multiply A+I with it?

Comment: "*like if it was a multiplication*" but its *not* multiplication.  Do not confuse exponentiation with multiplication.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think OP rather confused addition with multiplication.

Comment: @amsmath even then $(A\times B)^{-1}=B^{-1}\times A^{-1}\neq A^{-1}\times B^{-1}$ in most situations.

Comment: @amsmath I also confused with the transpose of a matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to apply the [freshman's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream).  This is wrong and incorrect to do in almost every scenario and situation.  There is no reason ahead of time to expect $(A+I)^{-1}$ to be $A^{-1}+I^{-1}$.

In general, one should not expect $(a+b)^n$ to equal $a^n+b^n$.

Comment: lol this happens so often it has a name to it? thanks , i assumed it was possible to simplify it...